# Controls vertical alignment with grid on the left and right

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a custom listbox with a label and a checkbox in each row. I would like to have the label on the far left and the checkbox on the far right.

**approach:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbFieldsreq" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="513,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Content="{Binding name, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <Label  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" /> <!--Empty column -->
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ticked  ,Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**current look:**

[image: listbox]

Thx

Comment: have you tried  `<Label  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" /> `

Comment: I would use `<DockPanel>` i.e. `<Label DockPanel.Dock="Left"/> <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Right"/> <Label/><!--empty column goes as last -->` HTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XAML is mostly fine. All you really need to do is to set the [`ListBox.HorizontalContentAlignment` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) to `"Stretch"`. This basically forces each item in the collection to stretch to fill with entire `Width` of the related `ListBoxItem`. However, you could improve this further by setting the [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=vs.110).aspx) to `True`. Setting this in conjunction with the `SharedSizeGroup` property enables us to ensure that the column `Width`s of each column of the `DataTemplate` are the same. Try this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbFieldsreq" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="LabelColumn" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="CheckBoxColumn" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
                <!--Empty column -->
                <Label Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" IsChecked="{Binding ticked, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```